# SetUID doesn't work properly with Samba on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I got Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running with the newest version of Samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.11).

I configured a share and all the appropriate unix permissions on the directories themselves. Tested it and everything works just fine.

**My hierarchy looks like this:**

[[image: Image of the directories]

There is one group for each subfolder e.g.: **geschaeftsleitung, it, verwaltung** and one user per group.

Share configuration within **smb.conf**:

```
create mask = 6770
directory mask = 6770
force create mask = 6770
force directory mask = 6770
```

So the owner and the group have full access to those subfolders.

I set the **setuid**

```
chmod u+s
```

and **guid**

```
chmod g+s
```

for all of those subfolders.

So if I am correct, every directoy and file created inside those subfolders should automatically set the owner to root and the group to the superior group of that specific subfolder.

It does that for the group but not for the owner. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UElWi.png)

The user connected to the share and creating a directory or file becomes the owner, despite my previous settings.

---

Is there some weird behaviour with unix permissions in combination with samba?

Or does `chmod u+s` simply not work on my Ubuntu distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this Wiki page the `setuid` is ignored on directories.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

> **setuid and setgid on directories[edit]**
>
> The setuid and setgid flags,
>   when set on a directory, have an entirely different meaning.
>
> Setting the setgid permission on a directory ("chmod g+s")
>
> 1. causes new files and subdirectories created within it to inherit its
>      group ID, rather than the primary group ID of the user who created the
>      file (the owner ID is never affected, only the group ID).
> 2. Newly
>      created subdirectories inherit the setgid bit. Thus, this enables a
>      shared workspace for a group without the inconvenience of requiring
>      group members to explicitly change their current group before creating
>      new files or directories.
> 3. only affects the group ID of new files and
>      subdirectories created after the setgid bit is set, and is not applied
>      to existing entities.
> 4. does not affect group ID of the files that are
>      created elsewhere and moved to the directory in question. The file
>      will continue to carry the group ID that was effected when and where
>      it was created. Setting the setgid bit on existing subdirectories must
>      be done manually, with a command such as the following:
>
>    ```
>    root@foo# find /path/to/directory -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \;
>    ```
>
> **The
>   setuid permission set on a directory is ignored on UNIX and Linux
>   systems.[4]**
>
> FreeBSD can be configured to interpret it analogously to setgid,
>   namely, to force all files and sub-directories to be owned by the top
>   directory owner.[5] On systems derived from BSD, directories behave as
>   if their setgid bit was always set, regardless of its actual value. As
>   is stated in open(2), "When a new file is created it is given the
>   group of the directory which contains it."